# Deleted Inbox by mistake Outlook.com

Tags: outlook.com

I deleted my Inbox by mistake. Have over 5000 mails in Deleted folder. If I select the 'All' checkbox I don't get the option to Move to Inbox. But if I select a group of mails, say 30, I do. Is there a way to bulk move all mails back to Inbox?

Comment: Have you tried other email clients, e.g. the one that comes with Windows 10, or Outlook?

Comment: It's on web I'm using outlook.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to connect with an email client (Outlook 2016, Thunderbird) over IMAP.
When your Mails are synchronized you can move all from the **Deleted Mails** to your **INBOX** again.

Be aware that to move the mails will take a few moments !

[Outlook.com - Using IMAP with lLients](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-your-Outlook-com-account-to-another-mail-app-73f3b178-0009-41ae-aab1-87b80fa94970?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't choose more than a page at a time to act on with the web interface. (See [this answer from answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-ofolders/how-to-select-all-mail-from-a-folder-at-outlookcom/9bba634e-bd7b-42f0-a88b-c9aca24c41b3).)

To select all of the messages on a page, click the checkbox at the top of the list (next to the "View" menu, which defaults to "All").

Open the "Move to" menu at the top of the page, and select "Inbox".